# "fold" an array of hashes, recursion required?

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

This is a simple example of my starting point :

```
[
 { 'drink' => [ 'hard', 'soft' ] },
 { 'hard' => [ 'beer', 'wine' ] },
 { 'soft' => [ 'water', 'orange_juice' ] },
 { 'food' => [ 'fruit', 'veg', 'meat' ] },
 { 'fruit' => [ 'apples', 'bananas', 'pears' ] }
 { 'veg' => [ 'cabbages', 'potatoes', 'carrots' ] },
 { 'potatoes' => [ 'king_edward', 'sweet', 'russet' ] }
]
```

I need to iterate over this, and "fold in" where the key to the values in a hash, is the value in another hash, so I end up with :

```
  [ 
    { 'drink' => [ { 'hard' => [ 'beer', 'wine' ] }, { 'soft' => [ 'water', 'orange_juice' ] } ] },
    { 'food' => [ { 'fruit' => [ 'apples', 'bananas', 'pears' ] },  
              { 'veg' => [ 'cabbages', { 'potatoes' => [ 'king_edward', 'sweet', 'russet' ] }, 'carrots' ] }
  ]
```

The nesting could be any level of depth, but the result will always end up being an array of hashes at its outermost ( if that makes sense ), with one or more hash in that array.

**Edit:** Or as suggested in comment below, the result structure could just be a hash, with 'drink', and 'food' keys pointing to the respective nested values in that hash. ( The items are not necessarily unique, two or more keys could point to the same value/s ).

I can iterate over an array and/or hash with ".each" etc., and apply logic and build the result structure iteratively, but I'm struggling with what I think is the recursive nature of this problem, in terms of making sure that everything that can be nested gets nested to any depth ( if that makes sense ).

I'm not looking for a complete solution, but just a mental nudge in the right direction as to how to go about creating a solution for this, because at the moment I keep venturing down dead-ends..

Comment: You can do it iteratively if you keep a lookup table of every element and plug in the child for any match, assuming the constraint holds that for each item, its parent must already exist earlier in the structure. More details seem necessary: is each item unique, for example? Are these symbols or variables? Best to show your data structures as valid Ruby to eliminate any guesswork.

Comment: Are you sure you want those extra arrays? Should it be `{ 
  drink => { hard => [ beer, wine ], soft => [ water, orange_juice ] },
  food => {
    fruit => [ apples, bananas, pears ],
    veg => [ cabbages, { potatoes => [ king_edward, sweet, russet ] }, carrots ]
  }
}`

Comment: @ggorlen, they are not variables. Although my simple example suggests they might be, the items are not necessarily unique, potentially two different keys could have the same value. Imagine a situation where one file references another file, and two different files could refer to the same file.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks, ultimately I want to convert the result into JSON, so I think either is ok (?), and your suggestion appears simpler, so perhaps that is better.

Comment: Could you have `[{'drink' => ['hard'] }, { 'hard' => ['drink'] }]` or a more indirect cycle?

Comment: I believe you need to first perform a [Topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the directed arcs associated with your data (e.g. `['drink', 'hard']`, `['drink', 'soft']`,...) to create a directed graph. That can be done if and only if the graph is *acyclic* (no directed cycles). I believe the algorithms that construct such graphs detect directed cycles.

Comment: Did you dropped by purpose the string 'meat' that is a value in the original hash with key 'food'? If it so does it mean that all values that are not a key in other hashes have do be deleted? Are keys in the hashes unique or you could have both `{ 'drink' => [ 'hard', 'soft' ] }`, { 'drink' => [ 'small', 'soft' ] }?

Answer (score 0):

Edited: this updated solution is recursive as well, as the previous. I added some case in the input to show how can nest at a deepr level (beer for example)

```rb
def rec_map(to_map, collection, mapped)
  if to_map.empty?
    mapped
  else
    case to_map[0]
    when String
      current_key = to_map[0]
      mapped_key = collection.find(-> {current_key}) { |item_hash| item_hash.has_key?(current_key) }
      if current_key == mapped_key
        rec_map(to_map[1..-1], collection, mapped << current_key)
      else
        with_mapped_values = Hash.new
        mapped_values = rec_map(mapped_key[current_key], collection, [])
        with_mapped_values[current_key] = mapped_values
        rec_map(to_map[1..-1], collection, mapped << with_mapped_values)
      end
    when Hash
      key = to_map[0].keys.first
      values = to_map[0].values.flatten
      with_mapped_values = Hash.new
      mapped_values = rec_map(values, collection, [])
      with_mapped_values[key] = mapped_values
      rec_map(to_map[1..-1], collection, mapped << with_mapped_values)
    else
      raise "Not supported given #{to_map[0].class} expected String or Hash"
    end
  end
end

def key_has_match(key, collection)
  if collection.empty?
    return false
  else
    case collection[0]
    when String
      key == collection[0] || key_has_match(key, collection[1..-1])
    when Hash
      key_has_match(key, collection[0].values.flatten) ||
      key_has_match(key, collection[1..-1])
    else
      raise "Not supported given #{collection[0].class} expected String or Hash"
    end
  end
end

def rec_fold(to_fold, collection, folded)
  if to_fold.empty?
    folded
  else
    key = to_fold[0].keys.first
    if key_has_match(key, collection)
      rec_fold(to_fold[1..-1], collection, folded)
    else
      with_mapped_values = Hash.new
      values = to_fold[0][key]
      with_mapped_values[key] = rec_map(values, collection, [])
      rec_fold(to_fold[1..-1], collection, folded << with_mapped_values)
    end
  end
end

if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  original = [
 { 'drink' => [ 'hard', 'soft' ] },
 { 'hard' => [ 'beer', 'wine' ] },
 { 'beer' => [ 'lager', 'stout', 'ale' ] },
 { 'lager' => [ 'draught', 'bottle' ] },
 { 'draught' => [ 'pint', 'half' ] },
 { 'soft' => [ {'water' => ['tap', 'bottle']}, 'orange_juice' ] },
 { 'food' => [ 'fruit', 'veg', 'meat' ] },
 { 'fruit' => [ 'apples', 'bananas', {'pears'=> ['anjou', 'bartlett', 'concorde']} ] },
 { 'veg' => [ 'cabbages', 'potatoes', 'carrots' ] },
 { 'potatoes' => [ 'king_edward', 'sweet', 'russet' ] },
 { 'sweet' => [ 'red', 'brown', 'white' ] },
 {'bottle' => ['green', 'red', 'blue']},
 {'bartlett' => ['Woven baskets', 'Bags', 'Modified atmosphere']}
]

pp rec_fold(original, original, [])
end 

# [{"drink"=>
#    [{"hard"=>
#       [{"beer"=>
#          [{"lager"=>
#             [{"draught"=>["pint", "half"]},
#              {"bottle"=>["green", "red", "blue"]}]},
#           "stout",
#           "ale"]},
#        "wine"]},
#     {"soft"=>
#       [{"water"=>["tap", {"bottle"=>["green", "red", "blue"]}]},
#        "orange_juice"]}]},
#  {"food"=>
#    [{"fruit"=>
#       ["apples",
#        "bananas",
#        {"pears"=>
#          ["anjou",
#           {"bartlett"=>["Woven baskets", "Bags", "Modified atmosphere"]},
#           "concorde"]}]},
#     {"veg"=>
#       ["cabbages",
#        {"potatoes"=>
#          ["king_edward", {"sweet"=>["red", "brown", "white"]}, "russet"]},
#        "carrots"]},
#     "meat"]}]
```

Comment: It took a few days on and off to figure it out, and the original problem also morphed which didnt help, but I finally managed to get a solution to what I needed using recursion, ( the challenge for me was getting the recursive call in the right place, it was obvious once I got right ). When I find some time I’ll update this page again, and list an example of the code I used to solve.

Comment: It would be a great idea if you post your solution to see in which way is different than the one I posted.